# Easy Install for Python and Eclipse Library Paths

Tags: python, eclipse, easy-install

Recently I found about this tool `easy_install` that help me to easy install additional python modules. The problem is that for each module it creates additional `*.egg` folder (sometime there is only an egg file?) (no source?) and I don't know how to setup eclipse paths.

By default I have included `C:\Python26\Lib\site-packages` and this is enough when I install python modules from source... but not when I'm using `easy_intall`

For example `django` instaled with `easy_install` is located in `C:\Python26\Lib\site-packages\django-1.2.5-py2.6.egg\django` and installed from source it's located in `C:\Python26\Lib\site-packages\django`

In fact when I'm using `easy_install` all installed modules are working without a problem, the only problem is that eclipse can't locate where is the source and gives me a false unresolved import errors

Where I'm wrong?

[image: Eclipse Setup]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming that eclipse does not search the egg files for source.  Eggs, like jar files in Java, are just zipfiles of python code with some included metadata.

You'll also note that in site-packages you've got easy-install.pth and setuptools.pth files.  Those files are parsed by python and used to add other directories and egg files to your PYTHONPATH (import sys; sys.path) so that Python can find the code in those locations.  Eclipse isn't seeing those imports as valid because it is most likely not setup to take pth files into account.

To get Eclipse to recognize that Django is really installed you may want to try removing your easy_installed django package and reinstalling it with:

```
easy_install --always-unzip django
```

That way rather than installing a compressed egg file you'll have a normal package directory that eclipse should have a fairly easy time opening.

Alternatively, in your screenshot above it looks like you may just need to explicitly add each egg file you want eclipse to use.

Comment: I tried it but the destination folder is the same again. But now I know what err file is and found that eclipse have [New egg/zip file(s)] button, that will import module if there is no source code. Thank you :)